# Summarizing Multiple Columns of Data Using Pipes

Tags: r

I'm looking to report the min, max, and mean of certain columns (`price`, `age`, and `dist`)from the `houses` data set using pipes in a concise tibble. For now, I have the following code which produces a rather inelegant solution with a 1x9 tibble:

```
houses %>% 
  select(price, age, dist) %>%
  summarize_each(list(min = min, max = max, mean = mean))
```

I was hoping to create a more organized solution using pipes with the selected data as rows and the summary stats (min, max, mean) as columns resulting in a 3x3 tibble. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may first get the data in long format and then calculate summary statistics for each column. Here is an example with `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, disp, cyl) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(min = min(value, na.rm = TRUE), 
            max = max(value, na.rm = TRUE), 
            mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))

#  name    min   max   mean
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 cyl     4     8     6.19
#2 disp   71.1 472   231.  
#3 mpg    10.4  33.9  20.1
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to output a `dataframe`:

```
library(dplyr)
houses %>% 
  summarise(across(c(price,age,dist),c(max,min,mean))) %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = T) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rename(Max=V1, Min=V2, Mean=V3)
```

A possible solution to output a `tibble`:

```
library(dplyr)
houses %>% 
  summarise(across(c(price,age,dist),c(max,min,mean))) %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = T) %>% 
  tibble(Max=unlist(.[,1]),Min=unlist(.[,2]),Mean=unlist(.[,3])) %>% 
  select(Max,Min,Mean)
```

**EDIT (2021-10-01)**

A very short solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfc(c("Max","Min","Mean"),
        ~ tibble(!!sym(.x) := apply(select(houses, price, age, dist),2,tolower(.x))))
```

Comment: In each place where data should show, the data frame displays <dbl [1]>. How can this be fixed? Also, is there a way to add labels to the rows with the names of the selected data?

Comment: That only occurs when you try to convert the dataframe to a tibble -- the dataframe is correct!

Comment: If I didn't change the code from what you wrote, why is this occurring?

Comment: I have just added a solution to output a tibble. Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to add row labels?

Comment: Yes, just add the following code to mine: `%>% 
  mutate(rn=c("price","age","dist")) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("rn")`

Comment: Be aware, however, that `tibbles` do not support rownames: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html By applying the code in my previous comment, the `tibble` is converted to a `dataframe`.